# Pandas Series Boolean operation on integers only

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, boolean, series

I parsed a series of Excel files as df using Pandas.
In a given column, I'm trying to get the index of the maximum value below a certain value (7000).

```
df[columnname][df[columnname]._get_numeric_data() < 7000].idxmax()
```

The Excel files are not really well done, but I can't modify them. There is a lot of metadata (text, dates, etc.) around the data fames. when I parse the file, dates listed below the data frame also appear in the columns.

The script thus raises the following error:

```
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to int
```

Any way I can exclude date types from the operation to only consider values.

nb. Rows with dates vary from one file to another, some files have none of these rows.

Comment: Could you paste few rows of data, it helps in understanding the inconsistency?

Comment: And, `_get_numeric_data()` returns numeric columns from a dataframe. It doesn't work the way you intended to use.

Answer (score -1):

thanks for the help. JonhE, your method did not work because the mask:

```
mask = df['x'].map( lambda x: type(x) != str ) & (df['x'] < 8)
```

kept raising the same error:

```
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to int
```

maybe the .map() was trying to apply both the mask and the operation:

```
(df['x'] < 8)
```

at the same time, the latter raising the error.

Nonetheless, I found a solution by integrating a mask:

```
mask1 = df[columnname].map(lambda x: type(x) == int)
```

to a second mask:

```
mask2 = df[columnname][mask] < maxval
```

I then used this second mask in the operation:

```
maxsearch = df[columnname][mask2[mask2].index].idxmax()
```

for which I had to rely on the .index to avoid to raising a key error.

Final solution:

```
return df[columnname][(df[columnname][df[columnname].map(lambda x: type(x) == int)] < maxval)[df[columnname][df[columnname].map(lambda x: type(x) == int)] < maxval].index].idxmax()
```

Sure there is a simple way.